# twilio preflight feature for android and ios

Tags: twilio

By using Preflight feature, connection can be confirmed for test.
It can be developed for javascript by using this api

https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.8.0-beta.1/docs/PreflightTest.html

Howeve I cannot find it for android and ios
And I want to use it for flutter app

Question1: is there a preflight feature for ios and android?
if not is there a plan to develop it?

Question2: is there a way to develop similar feature with existing api?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is currently no preflight feature for the iOS and Android versions of Twilio Video.

I think it is something you could build yourself though. The code for the JavaScript version is here: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/tree/master/lib/preflight. It sets up a connection, collects WebRTC stats for the duration of the connection and reports on the stats once the connection is closed. I'd recommend reading through that code to see how it is achieved and whether you could do the same in your Flutter app.

Comment: when you say to use the JS code there as guide in android, do you mean to run that in an embedded web browser or how else can we run such diagnostics in android? in my case it's a native android app, not flutter. if it *is* to run it in an embedded browser, do you know how reliable are the results from an embedded browser vs what the user would get via the native android sdk? thank you

Comment: I meant literally reimplement the JavaScript code in the platform you’re building it on, not run the JS itself.

Comment: ok, i see. Thank you. any plans for a diagnostics tool for android? either a general Twilio Diagnostics SDK or as functionality of the Video SDK maybe?

Comment: I honestly don’t know, sorry.